# pattern fill svg and colorpicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, svg, color-picker

I wanna change the color of pattern fill svg using bootstrap-colorpicker-master. Then send the url of the svg with POST Method to database.

I've tried this but still not working:

The Html code :

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8px'>
    <rect width='8' height='8px' id='bg_color' fill='#ffff00'/>
    <path d='M0 0L8 8ZM8 0L0 8Z' stroke-width='1' stroke='#1e292d'/>
</svg>
<div class="input-append color bscp" data-color="#ffff00"  id="cp1">
    <input id="game_color" class="span5" style="height:20px; width:400px;" value>
    <span class="add-on" style="height:20px; width:20px; padding:0 0"><i style="height:14px; width:14px; margin:3px 3px" onclick="stripedColor()"></i></span>
</div>
<input id="game_color_striped" type="hidden" name="g_color" >
```

The script I'm using :

```
var url = 'url("' + b64 + '")';
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(svg.cloneNode(true));

var b64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(div.innerHTML);

$(function(){

        $('#cp1').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
            document.getElementById('bg_color').fill = '#'+event.color.toHex();
            //document.getElementById('game_color').value = b64;
            document.getElementById("game_color_striped").value = url;
                    });

        });
```

Is there any help?

Comment: not working in what way? What is it doing that it should not, or not doing that it should?

Comment: @RobertLongson the game_color_striped value doesn't change

Comment: It's not changing because you are not changing it.  You are initialising variable `url` once at the top and never changing it.  In fact you are not even initialising `url` properly because you seem to be usng `b64` before it is itself set.   Perhaps you are showing us code out of context. It would be helpful if you created a code snippet, jsfiddle, etc so we can see your real code.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this line

```
document.getElementById('bg_color').fill = '#'+event.color.toHex();
```

There's no fill property on that element. There's a fill CSS mapped attribute that you could set with `setAttribute` e.g.

document.getElementById('bg_color').setAttribute('fill', '#'+event.color.toHex());

or you could set a fill style via

```
document.getElementById('bg_color').style.fill = '#'+event.color.toHex()
```